# Migrate Magento 1.14 EE to 1.9 CE

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, magento-upgrade

I need to migrate magento 1.14 EE to 1.9 CE. 
Can anyone tell me the steps to perform

thanks.

Comment: correct word for it - **downgrade**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Magento EE has many advanced features as compared to Magento CE (Open Source Edition), direct migration is not possible (as I know).

I can suggest a process (rebuilding the site afresh on community version) which may seem a bit lengthy but it will work for sure.

The key here is to migrate the most useable code from EE version to CE version.

But before this, a complete analysis of the project is required. Please have a look at the following steps:

> Analysis:

- Identify and document any custom modifications/ changes done in EE version and ascertain if all these can be emulated in CE version.
- Make a list of Extensions installed and check If the CE versions of the extensions are also available on Magento Marketplace.
- Create another web hosting account wherein you may load the CE version for migration. The original EE installation should never be disturbed till you are sure that CE version is ready to replace EE version.

> Migration:

The migration involves the following:

- Theme Migration (Copy **app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}**, **skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}**, **js** etc. folders)
- Data Migration (Export products, customers, orders, attributes, etc. from EE and import to CE version database)
- Code Migration (Apart from core Magento CE code, everything needs to be either installed as an extension or to be developed as a custom module)

Apart from the above exercise, we need to truncate the URL rewrites table and reindex once the categories and products are in place.

I have tried to summarize the process in an easy way. Please let me know if you have any question or concern.

**Suggestion:** Since Magento 1.x will have active support until the next year, I would recommend creating the website in **Magento 2.x CE**.